# How can I embed cover art to a video file so it can be seen in iTunes

Tags: cocoa, itunes, movie

I'm trying to add an image to a mov video file so it appears as cover when I add that file to iTunes. I'm really lost with this. I really don't know where to search. It's a iTunes, Quicktime or filesystem thing?. I mean, where is the image supposed to be?. It's an image stored internally by iTunes or it's embedded into the file?.

I'm almost sure you can add the image to the file itself. I'd appreciate any help pointing the right direction to research.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you already check out this TechNote: [Adding metadata to a QuickTime movie using the QuickTime MetaData APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1515/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004227)

Comment: Wow!. Thanks!. Great article. Didn't know it. I'm gonna read it right now.

Comment: Well. After a lot of trial and digging I found that since I'm using ARC in my project, and so forced to use 64-bit only target, the code of the Technote mentioned won't work. :/ Any workaround?. I can't believe its so difficult to set the artwork image of a movie.

Comment: What's the deployment target for your app, is OS X 10.7+ acceptable or do you have to support prior versions? (Actually, I should have asked this first…apologies for sending you in 32-bit land!) If 10.7+ _is_ an acceptable requirement, check out the `AVAssetExportSession` and `AVMutableMetadataItem` classes in conjunction with the `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` export preset — that should not transcode your media but only add the metadata you specify.

Comment: Thank you very much, danyowdee. 10.7+ is perfect for me. That's just what I want to do. I don't want to transcode or copy to temp file. The process should be as fast as possible.  I'll try and comment the results here.

Comment: After take a look at AVFoundation framework and dig into Apple Mac Developer Center Forum, seems clear that it's not possible to add metadata using this framework UPDATING a movie file, right now. AVFoundation do not offer a updateMovieFile like QTKit so the only choice is to write a destination file and that is unacceptable for my project even without transcoding. Too bad. :(

Comment: Well, can you not keep a URL to the source, export to temp move temp to source URL atomically or is that unacceptable? If you need keep hard-links to the source, there's a C function to atomically swap two file's contents…

Comment: The function I meant is `exchangedata` — it's pretty low level (part of the vfs syscalls) but straight forward to use.

Comment: Yes I could do that but the time it would cost will make my app unusable. It needs to process a batch of movie files and I just can't afford to copy and move every movie in the list. I think I'll pass until something different appears. Thank you very much for your help, dude. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end I followed danyowdee's advice and used AVFoundation framework to add artwork metadata to my movie files. I think this may be considered the answer to my question.

Apple has rejected my app, however, arguing that it writes files outside the allowed folders. WTF?. First they don't add an updateMovie method as in QTKit and then they complain about writing movies. How do I suppose to do that?. :/